# How to get all Movies that are playing on a MovieTheater?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have the following eloquent entities:

- Movie
- MovieSession
- MovieTheater
- MovieTheaterRoom

Table structure:

```php
Schema::create('movies', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
});

Schema::create('movie_theaters', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name')->index();
    $table->string('slug')->index()->unique();
    $table->string('description')->index()->nullable();
    $table->longText('content')->nullable();

    $table->unsignedInteger('picture_id')->nullable();
    $table->foreign('picture_id')
         ->references('id')
         ->on('media');

    $table->boolean('activated')->default(true);

    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create('movie_theater_rooms', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name')->index();
    $table->string('description')->index()->nullable();
    $table->longText('content')->nullable();

    $table->boolean('activated')->default(true);

    $table->unsignedInteger('movie_theater_id');
    $table->foreign('movie_theater_id')
        ->references('id')
        ->on('movie_theaters')
        ->onDelete('cascade');

    $table->unsignedInteger('picture_id')->nullable();
    $table->foreign('picture_id')
        ->references('id')
        ->on('media');

    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create('movie_sessions', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');

    $table->dateTime('starts_in');
    $table->dateTime('ends_in');

    $table->unsignedInteger('movie_theater_room_id');
    $table->foreign('movie_theater_room_id')
        ->references('id')
        ->on('movie_theater_rooms')
        ->onDelete('cascade');

    $table->unsignedInteger('movie_id');
    $table->foreign('movie_id')
        ->references('id')
        ->on('movies')
        ->onDelete('cascade');

    $table->boolean('activated')->default(true);

    $table->timestamps();
});
```

where a **MovieTheater** hasMany **MovieTheaterRoom**s, each **MovieTheaterRoom** hasMany **MovieSession**s and each **MovieSession** belongsTo a **Movie**.

What I'm trying, is to get all **Movie**s that are playing today on a **MovieTheater** by its `$movieTheaterId`, but since it is a long relation, I'm unable of retrieve such collection.

This is what I'have tried:

```php
public function scopeGetMoviesShowingTodayOnMovieTheater($movieTheaterId)
{
    return Movie::whereHas('sessions', function ($query) use ($movieTheaterId) {
        // $query->whereDate('starts_in', Carbon::today());

        $query->whereHas('movieTheaterRoom', function ($query) use ($movieTheaterId) {
            $query->where('movie_theater_id', $movieTheaterId);
        });
    });
}
```

When calling `App\Models\Movie::getMoviesShowingTodayOnMovieTheater(1)->get()` this is what I got:

> PHP Recoverable fatal error:  Object of class Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder could not be converted to string in .../vendor/illuminate/support/Str.php on line 338

I have also tried to use this package `staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep` like this:

```php
class MovieTheater extends Model {
    use HasRelationships;

    public function movies()
    {
        return $this->hasManyDeep(Movie::class, [MovieSession::class, MovieTheaterRoom::class]);
    }
}
```

And when calling `App\Models\MovieTheater::find(1)->movies()->get()`

This is the output:

> Illuminate/Database/QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'movie_sessions.movie_theater_id' in 'field list' (SQL: select `movies`.*, `movie_sessions`.`movie_theater_id` from `movies` inner join `movie_theater_rooms` on `movie_theater_rooms`.`id` = `movies`.`movie_theater_room_id` inner join `movie_sessions` on `movie_sessions`.`id` = `movie_theater_rooms`.`movie_session_id` where `movie_sessions`.`movie_theater_id` = 1)'

Where I'm wrong?

Comment: What does your table-structure look like?

Comment: I have added my migrations to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception

> Object of class Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder could not be converted to string in .../vendor/illuminate/support/Str.php on line 338

is thrown because you didn't provide the $query parameter in your scope definition. Your code will try to convert the movie theater id to a Builder instance, which fails.

Try to refactor your code to this:

```
/**
 * Scope a query to only select movies that are showing in a certain theater.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder  $query
 * @param  int  $movieTheaterId
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
 */
public function scopeGetMoviesShowingTodayOnMovieTheater($query, $movieTheaterId)
{
    return $query
        ->whereHas('sessions.movieTheaterRoom', function ($query) use 
        ($movieTheaterId) {
            $query->whereMovieTheaterId($movieTheaterId);
        });
}
```

I've also added dot notation in the `whereHas` statement to query a nested relation.

Comment: I still getting the error: `PHP Recoverable fatal error:  Object of class Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder could not be converted to string in .../vendor/illuminate/support/Str.php on line 338`

Comment: You get this exception because your scope definition is wrong, it should return a query builder. See updated answer.

Comment: But this is what I'm returning.

Comment: That's right, I was too quick. The problem is that you skipped the query builder parameter. Your code tries to convert the movie theater id to a query builder instance.

Comment: So, what should I do? This may be because I'm using a scoped function?

Comment: Just follow the example in this answer, provide the $query parameter in the scope definition, and define the movie theater id as a second parameter.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Can you make it like an answer so I can mark the question as Answered?

Comment: Great! I've changed the structure of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep` you should make the order like this

```
class MovieTheater extends Model {
    use HasRelationships;

    public function movies()
    {
        return $this->hasManyDeep(Movie::class, [MovieTheaterRoom::class, MovieSession::class]);
    }
}
```

Example order:
[image]